# MySql - select from main table with a lot of connected tables

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

I have a main table, which is related to 10 other tables through one-to-many relationships.

For example:

```
main Table           table1               table2
----------           -------              -------
id *                 id*                  id*
name                 mainTableId **       mainTableId **
                     column1              column2
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 On table1.mainTableId = main_table.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 On table2.mainTableId = main_table.id
...
```

The problem is that I am getting a lot of results back, since each result in `main_table` is being multiplied by all the results in `table1`, `table2`, etc.

I would like to use only one `SELECT` query, since querying the database 10 times takes a long time.

Retrieving 100 results from each table is good enough for my needs, but trying to do the following resulted in an error that `limit is not supported with a sub query`:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 WHERE id in (
    SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE mainTableId = mainTable.id LIMIT 100
)
```

I am using AWS Aurora. How can I improve this query?

Comment: you need condition on your join

Comment: also try group by and select only necessary fields (not *), and you get error because Limit cut whole final result of query, not subselects.

Comment: not true - the limit is inside the  () of the select

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON main_table.id = table1.mainTableId
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON main_table.id = table2.mainTableId
...
```

For the second question you could just fetch 100 rows from the other tables and join them instead!

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 100)a ON main_table.id = a.mainTableId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 LIMIT 100)b ON main_table.id = b.mainTableId
...
```

Comment: I don't understand what did you add to my query... I had the on in the query, but the multiple results still happens. about the second question - as I wrote, I got an error that limit is not available for sub queries

Comment: The query you posted does not have "ON". About the second query, I just checked, there is no problem with using LIMIT in subquery, but you have to alias it. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: the limit need to be on the results, in this the limit is before adding the condition with the main table